# React Native Google-Maps-IOS-Utils manual linking

Tags: swift, react-native

There are known issues with react-native-maps while using google maps on IOS (caused by 'use_frameworks!'). [This](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/b721e95a500d0c9a4fd93738e83fc86c2a57ac89/Swift.md) guide shows us to solve the error. But I can't apply it. I have some questions about this doc.

*Add a bridging header file with #import "GMUMarkerClustering.h" (note the relative path).* **What is a relative path and how can I note that?**
And should I import this bridging file to any other file?

Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: why don't you use ready solution https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps?

Comment: I tried but didn't work.